# Calling Tableview

Tags: iphone

How can we directly call UITableview in view controller classs....

Comment: what - this makes no sense without more details! If your view controller is a UITableViewController just call `[self view]`. Post some code so we can see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you added a table view to your nib file in Interface Builder, you need to bind it to an `IBOutlet` property in your class, then call the table view by its `IBOutlet` property.

If your view controller is a `UITableViewController` subclass, you can just use `self.tableView`.

Comment: Before people start warning you, you should go back to all your questions and tick the answers for each question which best help you. This gives us credit for our work and motivates other people to answer your future questions. Glad I could be of help.